# MongoDB Error: cannot unmarshal DNS message in ubuntu 18.04

Tags: mongodb, dns, client, driver, ubuntu-18.04

```
mongoimport --uri "mongodb+srv://****:****@qkart-node.bziv9x2.mongodb.net/qkart?retryWrites=true&w=majority" --drop --collection products --file data/products.json
```

MongoDB Version: v3.6.3
mongoimport go version: go1.10.1

The mongoDB Atlas has a version 6.0.5. So upon running the above command, it gives the following error:

```
Failed: Unsupported OP_QUERY command: drop. The client driver may require an upgrade. For more details see https://dochub.mongodb.org/core/legacy-opcode-removal
```

So, I've upgraded my mongodb version to the latest one i.e,
mongoDB version: v6.0.5
mongoimport go version: go1.19.3

Now the error I am getting is:
`error parsing command line options: error parsing uri: lookup qkart-node.bziv9x2.mongodb.net on 127.0.0.53:53: cannot unmarshal DNS message`

Can anybody tell me a fix, this error remains consistent after upgrading the mongoimport version which is basically by updating mongodb-org.

Comment: The advise in the error message is quite clear. Download the latest version of `mongoimport` (version: 100.7.0), then it should work

Comment: I've already install mongoimport 100.7.0, now the new error coming is cannot unmarshal DNS message

Comment: How did you export the data? Perhaps you have to use an old `mongoexport` to create the JSON and a new `mongoimport` to import into your new MongoDB.

Comment: No, it's not due to that. As I've mentioned it is giving me unmarshal DNS message, which basically depicts there's some issue with my DNS Configuration.

So, once I got to /etc/resolv.conf
And change the nameserver IP (127.0.0.53) by default to 8.8.8.8 (Google DNS), everything works perfectly. 

But I don't want to use public DNS. How can I do it with my default IP only i.e, (127.0.0.53)

Comment: Ip `127.0.0.53` the the loopback IP, i.e. **every** Ip between `127.0.0.1` and `127.255.255.254` is basically the same! You should clearly prefer the hostname rather than IP-address which is also recommended by MongoDB (especially when using Mongo Atlas, because the IP may change at any time).

Comment: Can you tell me how can I do that, Here's the connection string I got from MongoDB Atlas to connect to my DB: 

mongoimport --uri "mongodb+srv://****:****@qkart-node.bziv9x2.mongodb.net/qkart?retryWrites=true&w=majority" --drop --collection products --file data/products.json

Comment: "But I don't want to use public DNS" is like yelling of a three years old baby. Simply use a public DNS or use a DNS of your domain which is setup properly. Usually a DNS request will be forwarded to a public DNS server anyway, see [this example](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_Name_System#Beispiel_Namensaufl%C3%B6sung) in German Wikipedia